# Parsing a simple text file using Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm an moderator of a forum and I need to prune all the bots that register on there.
As you can see below, I can list all the users by:

```
Username number_of_mssages register_date
```

Example:

```
- Thurman Valsin0190    0       Sat Jan 14, 2012 5:00 pm
- Rubye Tones01AD   0       Sat Jan 14, 2012 4:59 pm
```

I need a super simple Python little program that parses me each line of a text file, so I can get, from the string above, only the nick names.

```
- Thurman Valsin0190
- Rubye Tones01AD
```

**This means that the program has to delete for each line the 0 and everything that is behind him. The text is taken from a .txt file**.
I know this is not that difficult but I'm not a lot into Python.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are calling a username appears to be two separate things -- a nickname and a username.

Comment: "Thurman Valsin0190" is the username.

Comment: That `0` will always be `0`? or can be any one digit number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a python question really, it's a regex/string parsing question...

Is it correct to say that every line contains the nickname, a tab character, and then a 0?

Then it should be as simple as:

(assuming **line** contains a single line from the file)

```
nickname = line.split("\t")[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

consider using regular expressions:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s+0\s+')
pattern.findall('- Thurman Valsin0190    0       Sat Jan 14, 2012 5:00 pm')[0] 
# - Thurman Valsin0190
```

Comment: I need a generic program, not only for a single username.

Comment: @user963658 This is generic, the pattern is `match the substring before multiple white spaces following a 0 with trailing multiple whitespaces`. You may give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Why not split on 0 with leading spaces (or tabs) included as part of split key to avoid splitting other zeros:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        nick = line.split(" 0 ")[0].strip() # OR .split("\t0\t") if those are tabs
        print nick
```

Comment: And if I need to save the results on the same file, deleting the un-parsed lines? (I need only a text file with the pared lines, the ones only with the username)

Comment: Run this program with shell and redirect its output to another .txt file. Delete the original .txt  file and rename the new file to original file.

e.g.

python script.py > out.txt
rm filename.txt
mv out.txt filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

Parse by splitting on `" 0 "` string e.g., extract-nickname.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    nick, sep, rest = line.partition(" 0 ")
    if sep:
       print(nick.strip())
```

It assumes that nicknames can't contain `" 0 "` and leading/trailing whitespace is not a part of a nickname. Otherwise you could use `line.partition("\t")` if a tab character is a separator between `Username` and `number_of_mssages`.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/uJI27)

```
$ python extract-nickname.py log.txt
- Thurman Valsin0190
- Rubye Tones01AD
```

If you need to change the file inplace then you could specify `inplace=True` parameter to [`fileinput.input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) function.